# Boo Constructor Chaining

Tags: syntax, boo, constructor-chaining

In C# when I want to chain constructors together I'd do this...

```
public class OperationMacro : GeneratePropertyMacro {
    public OperationMacro() : base("Operation") {
        //Whatever else I need to do...
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent syntax in Boo?

Answer (score 3):

Found it (It stinks that the codehaus site is a little dodgy)

```
class JobMacro(GeneratePropertyMacro):
    public def constructor():
        super("ThisIsTheJobName")
```